# Passing Argument in GraphQL with Typescript Return an Empty Curly Brackets

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql

I just start learning GraphQL with Typescript. I want to pass an argument in a GraphQL function so I can return something dynamically. I have been stuck in this problem for about an hour and cannot find any help. Below is the codes on my project.

`schema.ts`

```js
export default gql`
type Query {
    fetchCourse(courseId: String!): String
}
`
```

`resolver.ts`

```js
export default {
    Query: {
        fetchCourse: (courseId: string): string => {
            console.log(courseId)
            return 'test'
            // I want to do someting like this when the argument is working
            // const data = await db('course').select('*').where('c_id', courseId).first()
            // return data.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

**GraphQL query on GraphiQL**

```
{
  fetchCourse(courseId: "1b9d6bcd-bbfd-4b2d-9b5d-ab8dfbbd4bed")
}
```

Currently the `Console.log()` outputing just an empty curly bracket (`{}`) or empty object in Javascirpt. What I expected this should give the argument itself (`1b9d6bcd-bbfd-4b2d-9b5d-ab8dfbbd4bed`)

I really appreciate all of your response. Thank you

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of painful hours, I finally found the solution. Maybe I don't provide enough information. I was using `Fastify` and `Mercurius`.

The solution is very simple, just need to add underscore (`_`) with `unknown` type in first argument and an object of desired type in second argument. For example if your query is something like this :

```
type Query {
    add(x: Int, y: Int): Int
}
```

and your resolver should like this

```
Query: {
    add: (_: unknown, { x, y }: { x: number, y: number }): number => {
        console.log(x, y)
        return x + y
    }
}
```

So the query for my question should be this

```
Query: {
        fetchCourse: async (_: unknown, { courseId }: { courseId: string }): Promise<string> => {
        const data = await db('course').select('*').where('c_id', courseId)
        return JSON.stringify(data)
    }
}
```